# Cole-cole plot curve collapses when trying to alter the valule of horisontal axis

Tags: nyquist-plot

I am a beginner and trying to simulate a cole-cole plot of a simple parallel circuit having two R, one coil and a capacitor. Image attaced, LTspice version is XVII, pc is windows7.

I've read this Q-A;[Bode plot graph: Frequency vs. Angular frequency]
[Bode plot graph: Frequency vs. Angular frequency](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/389894/bode-plot-graph-frequency-vs-angular-frequency)
but things does not seem to be the same.

When I checked out the current for R1, the graph goes well. So altered this curve from R2 to 1V/I(R2) as shown in this image in the upper left.

Then altered the vertical values; 85dB to -85dB, with the tick 5db, and clicked Nyquist. This seems works goo.

But when I alter the horizontal value; o.oohms - 1Mohms, the curve collapses.

Any tips will be very much appreciated, thanks!

p.s.; Incidentally I tried turned off [Autoranging], but the results was the same...

[image]

Comment: As I understand it , Cole-Cole plots are for phaser dielectric properties in the microwave band to establish a model from data, not discrete parts <1Hz https://www.ameteksi.com/products/software/zsimpwin

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Can you ask a specific answarable question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTspice doesn't have ohms, farads, etc, in the schematic editor, all it has is units, and they are case *insensitive*. That is, `m` stands for `milli` (`1e-3`), and so does `M`. So what you have is a step from `1` to `1e-3`. So do not bother adding `ohm`, it has no effect, you can just write `.ac oct 50 1 1meg`.

Also, LTspiceXVII orders the stepped values in increasing order, but I don't know if this also applies to `.AC` directives.

Comment: Hello Concerned_Citisen, thanks. your tip was fantastic to me. I did this.

Comment: @ChyFarm If you think the answer was helpful, mark it as answered by clicking on it (the select mark below the down-arrow). This will serve others, in the future, to know that the answer can be used for their problems, as well.

Comment: Concerned_Citizen, thanks again, was looking for that mark! Now did it.